# How To Create Folders Based on a Range of Numbers in Python

Tags: python

I want to create a few folders based on a given range of numbers. For example, I want to create folders 500 through 520. Is there a way to create these folders using the     `range(500, 520)` ?

Am I heading down the right path with this code?

```
    import os

    for i in range(500, 520):
        os.mkdir(r'C:\Dir' + i)
```

I know this is wrong since `i` is an integer, but can someone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string formatting:

```
os.mkdir(r'C:\Dir%s' % i)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `str()` to get a string representation of an integer:

```
for i in range(500, 520):
    os.mkdir(r'C:\Dir' + str(i))
```

However, it would probably be better to use string formatting instead, which gives more flexibility, such as including leading zeros:

```
for i in range(500, 520):
    os.mkdir(r'C:\Dir{:04d}'.format(i))
```